# python regex for parsing filenames

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm the worst for regex in general, but in python... I need help in fixing my regex for parsing filenames, e.g:

```
>>> from re import search, I, M
>>> x="/almac/data/vectors_puces_T12_C1_00_d2v_H50_corr_m10_70.mtx"
>>> for i in range(6):
...     print search(r"[vectors|pairs]+_(\w+[\-\w+]*[0-9]{0,4})([_T[0-9]{2,3}_C[1-9]_[0-9]{2}]?)(_[d2v|w2v|coocc\w*|doc\w*]*)(_H[0-9]{1,4})(_[sub|co[nvs{0,2}|rr|nc]+]?)(_m[0-9]{1,3}[_[0-9]{0,3}]?)",x, M|I).group(i)
...
```

It gives the following output:

```
vectors_puces_T12_C1_00_d2v_H50_corr_m10_70
puces_T
12_C1_00
_d2v
_H50
_corr
```

However, what I need is

```
vectors_puces_T12_C1_00_d2v_H50_corr_m10_70
puces
T12_C1_00
_d2v
_H50
_corr
```

I don't know what exactly is wrong. Thank you

Comment: so the problem is the `_T` in `puces_T`? or what? because you should know that `\w` includes `_` as a word char. \w is the equivalent of `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

Comment: Valid filename depends on the filesystem.

Comment: The problem is `puces` and `T12_C1_00` are thought to be separated, but my regex does not work so.  Do you suggest using `[0-9A-Za-z]` instead of `\w`? I tested with `[vectors|pairs]+_(\w+[\-[a-z]+]*[0-9]{0,4})([_T[0-9]{2,3}...` but the output is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that *`\w` would also match underscore* which you want to be a delimiter between `puces` and `T12_C1_00` in this case. Replace the `\w` with `A-Za-z\-`. Also, you should put the underscore between the appropriate saving groups:

```
(?:vectors|pairs)_([A-Za-z\-]+[0-9]{0,4})_([T[0-9]{2,3}_C[1-9]_[0-9]{2}]?)...
                                     HERE^
```

Works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"(?:vectors|pairs)_([A-Za-z\-]+[0-9]{0,4})_([T[0-9]{2,3}_C[1-9]_[0-9]{2}]?)(_[d2v|w2v|coocc\w*|doc\w*]*)(_H[0-9]{1,4})(_[sub|co[nvs{0,2}|rr|nc]+]?)(_m[0-9]{1,3}[_[0-9]{0,3}]?)",x, re.M|re.I).groups()
('puces', 'T12_C1_00', '_d2v', '_H50', '_corr', '_m10_70')
```

I've also replaced the `[vectors|pairs]` with `(?:vectors|pairs)` which is, I think, what you've actually meant - match either `vectors` or `pairs` literal strings, `(?:...)` is a syntax for a non-capturing group.

Comment: Thank you @alecxe. The problem with `.group(1)` is the grouped expression `_T12_C1_00` can or not appear, it is why I keep `_` inside the `[ ]`. It is the same case for `_corr` and `_70`, so an alternative filename can be: `"/almac/data/vectors_puces12_d2v_H50_m10.mtx"`, whose desirable result would be: `('puces', '_d2v', '_H50', '_m10')`

Comment: @Nacho got it. I think you need to add `_?` between the groups as opposed to putting undercores into capturing groups. Also, please see that note about `[vectors|pairs]` vs `(?:vectors|pairs)` - I think you have similar problem later in the expression.

Comment: @Nacho as a side note. Your expression is getting quite large and complicated. I suggest you break it down into multiple lines in a [verbose mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).

Comment: Thank you @alecxe, I used `?` as you said and it completely works :D

Comment: @Nacho don't say it works until you test it on every filename you can possibly have. And, even then you can only say that "it worked so far" :)

Comment: Indeed it just crashed for other file name `x="/almac/data/vectors_puces_d2v_H50_m10.mtx"` its output is `('puces', none, 'd2v', 'H5','0','m10')` instead of  `('puces', none, 'd2v', 'H50',none,'m10')`

Comment: @Nacho were you able to fix the latest problem? If not, could you post what expression you have now and I'll take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but you seem to be interested in what's between each underscore, so it may be simpler to split by it:

```
path, filename = os.path.split(x)
filename = filename.split('.')
fileparts = filename.split('_')
```

`fileparts` will then be this list:

```
vectors
puces
T12
C1
00
d2v
H50
corr
m10
70
```

And you can validate / inspect any part, e.g. `if fileparts[0] == 'vectors'` or `tpart = fileparts[2:4]`...

Comment: @alecxe D'oh! Fixed. We don't know how consistent a file name pattern he's expecting, so this solution might not work in his case.